# Where have I gone wrong? A basic question in physics (Mechanics)

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

A stone is dropped vertically in a velocity of $15$ minutes per second, from a point $40$ meters above the ground (excuse my poor English.).

a. How long will it take to the stone to hit the ground?

I answered it like this:

$v_0=15$, $a(t)=a_0=g$, $v(t)=v_0+gt$ $\Rightarrow x(t)=x_0+v_0t+{1\over 2}gt^2\Rightarrow x(t)=x_0+15t+gt^2$.

I denoted $x_0=0$, which derived $x(t_1)=40$ given $t_1$ is the time it takes to get to the ground.

Then I solve $x(t_1)=40=15t_1+4.9t_1^2$. I got that $t_1=1.7s$ sec, and the other option is negative.

**The problem is**: I was then asked: when will the stone be at 2 sec? 3 sec? That makes me feel like I got this all wrong. I am new to this an I am not sure I know what I am doing. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: The stone is thrown horizontally, gravity works vertically. That's what you missed. Also, check your units.

Comment: So that means the solution has to be more complex than that, I suppose. I don't know how to treat two forces going in different direction

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is no more complex. You have to use the equation
$y(t)=h_0+v_0t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$, where $h_0$ is the initial position ($40$m), and $v_0$ the initial velocity ($0$ in this case). Now, solve

$40-4.9t^2=0$

and use the original fórmula for the other questions too.

Comment: How did you get that $y(0)=-40$?
That is intricate for me conceptually.

Comment: I have edited your question to indicate that you are not including any horizontal motion or its analysis. If this is incorrect,I shall attempt to change it back.

Comment: Yes but that also changes the original form of the question I am asked, resulting in others believing it is correct and having no reason to correct me.

Comment: But why is $y(\text{requested time})=-40$ and not $0$? I used 0 which seemed reasonable but I see you used $-40$. Why is that?

Comment: Think that you are in the ground and drop the stone in a hole $40$m deep.

Comment: And why is $v_0=0$? What about 15? 
And still, I know how $-40$ can be admissible under some circumstances, but to me it seems like it went 40 meters to 0 and then another 40 meters. 80 meters down eventually. Can you be more thorough, please? I really appreciate your help so far.

Comment: Yes, you are rigth, I was confused. It needs only $40-4.9t²=0$. In less than 3 seconds the stone get to the ground. My first try was $t=4$ and the answer is almost $-40$. Sorry for that. I just corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
You have a problem in two dimension with:

$ \vec v_0=(v_0,0)^T$ (and I suppose your velocity is in meter/sec)

$\vec a=(0,-g)^T$

$\vec s_0=(40,0)$

Your equation of motion become:

$$
\vec s(t)=\dfrac{t^2}{2}\vec a+t \vec v_0+\vec s_0 \Rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}x(t)\\y(t) \end {bmatrix}=\dfrac{t^2}{2}\begin{bmatrix}0\\-g \end {bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}15\\0 \end {bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\40 \end {bmatrix}
$$
Solve the $y$ componet for $y(t)=0$ and you have the time to hit the ground, use this time in the $x$ componet and you find the point where the stone stops.

Comment: Okay I start to get it. I shall try to work it out.

Comment: The problem is that I look for $t_1$ such that $x(t_1)=(p,0)$ where $p$ is unknown. How do I deal with this?
Thank you so much so far.

Answer (score 1):

Don't feel bad.I think the wording of the problem is incorrect.If I had to guess,it would go something like this:"A stone is dropped vertically from a height of 40 meters above the ground at an initial velocity of 15 meters/sec.
We need to measure distance from 40 meters up toward the ground,If s = distance,
s = 0 at 40 meters up.The acceleration of gravity is about 9.8 meters/(sec^2)'
We start with the differential equation: d2/s2 = 9.8.(pardon the notation for
the second derivative.)Integrating ds/dt = 9.8t + v0.or ds/dt = 9.8t + 15.We
integrate again to get a formula for the distance,s. s = 4.9t^2 + 15t + s(0).
But s(0) = 0 and s = 40.This gives a quadratic equation in t=4.9t^2 + 15t - 40=0
Solve for t using the quadratic formula:9.8t=-15+sqrt(225+784),or t = 1.71 sec.
I think the other parts mean to say:"WHERE IS THE STONE AT 2 SEC.,3 SEC., ETC.
Just plug the values into your equation for s and you will find the stone will
hit the ground before these times can be reached.   Edwin Gray